# how to shorten blob url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob, rails-activestorage

I have ***has_one_attached :file*** in my attachment class.
url's length generated for download blob very long(access by ***file.blob.url***).

example:

```
https://57f2-77-237-188-145.ngrok-free.app/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhV1pqZG5wc01tMDRNMkowZFRob1lXbzJZbWh0WjNadWNYaHBNUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpUVdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1KaGMyRnNZVzB1Y0c1bklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZGlZWE5oYkdGdExuQnVad1k3QmxRNkVXTnZiblJsYm5SZmRIbHdaVWtpRG1sdFlXZGxMM0J1WndZN0JsUTZFWE5sY25acFkyVmZibUZ0WlRvS2JHOWpZV3c9IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyNC0wMS0yMFQxMjo0NDoxOS45OTJaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--e3916085b8f57e7e86100ea9ef4059ea655efe2a/11111111.png
```

this link very long, how to shorten blob url ?

Comment: Use a shortening service? Why would you care?

Comment: yes, use  https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener, but this solution is not suitable because it will be redirected to the same big address, but I have to shorten this address directly

Comment: Ok, so that's why I asked why you care, what are you trying to achieve here? Trying to answer this without more details is impossible. Eg. are you actually trying to switch to using publicly available (ie. insecure) access for your assets? You can achieve that by setting `public: true` in your `storage.yml` and obviously adding the requisite permissions on your asset server. See that particular use case [discussed here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access).

Comment: no, I don't want to give public access, but I want the length of the generated link to be shorter, because some systems do not accept a link with this length.

Comment: I think you'd need to look into how to change the algorithm that generates that private key then, change it to a simpler algorithm or maybe there's some options to use less bits or a shorter key or something. If you can be more specific (eg. Tell us how short it has to be) then maybe we can help

Comment: Yes, I want the length of the generated hash string before the file name to be shorter, for example, the value of the blob key(28 characters) field should be replaced and look like a path like https://57f2-77-237-188-145.ngrok-free.app/media/ognun8g1lv8b3untyytcd9pgpw0o/11111111.png